# How to set compiler options for activation groups in RPG or CL programs?

Tags: ibm-midrange, compiler-flags, rpgle, rpg, compiler-options

Is there any way to specify for a program source, what options for the activation group should be used during compilation?

In most of our programs on the as/400 we need to change the handling of the activation group (since the default behaviour is not at all useful...). Everytime I compile one of those programs, I have to remember to set the compiler options (that's in PDM: enter `14`, hit `F4`, change `DFTACTGRP` from `*YES` to `*NO`, hit `enter`, change `ACTGRP` to `*NEW` or `*CALLER`, depending on the program). So we have a lot of programs with comments at the beginning, having tons of exclamation marks, reminding the programmer to do so. And yes, sometimes you forget.

Is there any trick, so you don't have to remember yourself?

Comment: we actually hat the one for RPG, but it took me years to find a solution for CL, and it's hard to find in the internet, so I thaught I'd just post it here (and so never forget myself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set these compiler options in your RPGLE or your CLLE program sources.

In **RPG** you would use H-Specs at the top of your source to set compiler options. Like this:

```
HDFTACTGRP(*NO) ACTGRP(*CALLER)
```

Just add it to whatever else you have there, e.g.:

```
H DEBUG DATEDIT(*YMD)
H DFTACTGRP(*NO) ACTGRP(*CALLER)
H BNDDIR('SRVBNDDIR')
H MAIN(main)
F OUTPUT   O    F 3000        DISK    USROPN
D ...
 * procedures, etc.
```

In **CL**, there is a special command `DCLPRCOPT` which is not actually a command (as it is not executed during runtime), but a way to set compiler options.

```
DCLPRCOPT DFTACTGRP(*NO) ACTGRP(*CALLER)
```

Just put it at the top of your program. I normally put it behind the declaration of variables and before any real command. I also add a short comment, since I don't think everyone who might right my code might understand what is done there:

```
PGM        PARM(&SOMEPARM)
DCL        VAR(&SOMEPARM) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(*64)
DCL        VAR(&COUNTER) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(5 0) 

/* Setting options for compilation of this program */
/* This is a permanent job, so we want a *NEW activation group. */
DCLPRCOPT DFTACTGRP(*NO) ACTGRP(*NEW)

/* do actual work here in a loop */
/* ..... */

ENDPGM
```

Now, when you compile the program (just enter `14` in PDM and hit enter) it ends up with the activation group behaviour you specified in the source. Nothing left to remember yourself there.

Comment: One can also take a standard set of H specs, put them into a separate source member (call it say, STDHSPEC in QRPGLESRC) and then in your program, just issue a h/copy qrpglesrc,stdhspec  This way you don't need to remember each 'standard' option; they're all in one place.

Comment: You may have a group of members that should be compiled into a different activation group, so you could have such a copybook for each  named activation group, using whichever one was appropriate for your member.

Comment: DCLPRCOPT was added with V5R4M0 of OS/400's CL compiler.  If you are on a prior OS version (or if you use TGTRLS() to a prior version), attempts to use DCLPRCOPT will be rewarded with CPD0030 (Command DCLPRCOPT in library *LIBL not found.)

Comment: @BuckCalabro You're of course right, but since we have some ``*new`` and some ``*caller`` programs, I think for our part it's better to write it directly in the code (would excange one H-Spec for one /copy-spec, would make it more clear)

Comment: since it's been three month and nothing fundamentally new came, I'll exect my own solution...

Answer (score 2):

Another approach beside @kratenko suggestion.If you have default company settings, you could just change the command default value using `CHGCMDDFT` . e.g. `CHGCMDDFT CRTBNDRPG 'DFTACTGRP(*NO)'` and so on.. Our practice here is to always put settings at H-spec, especially for some special, non-standard settings. If someone forgot, default company settings will be used. One problem with this approach is your updated command probably will be reset back after OS update. You could use one of 2 approach

1. Put all your CHGCMDDFT in CL code and re-run after every OS upgrade
2. Duplicate,CHGCMDDFT required commands to a library and put this library in system library list

We change quite few of other command default and i prefer approach 1 above.
Hope this helps

Comment: upgrades are a problem there, right. And we don't need the same value for every program here, so it would not work. And: our system is >20years old (I know ILE is not that old -- only 19 years..) . Would not dare to change such a value globally, we have hundreds if not thousands of existing programs.

Answer (score 1):

H specs are definitely the way forward in 99% of programs but occasionally you'll find a compiler option that can't be set in an h spec. I've used source control software in the past which added these options as a comment in the source header and automatically applied it when compiling. To solve the problem of compiling on different machines we wrote our own compile utility that could read these comments. It's a fairly simple CL program, you just have to decide on a format for the comments.

Comment: if there is no H-spec, sure. Otherwise I would avoid adding an additional syntax and an additional tools you can forget using. But I suspect, that's your opinion, too.

Comment: Yeah sure, use h-specs as far as possible.